# Change output of HttpCookie to all uppercase in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, httpcookie

My website stores the username of a user after they login (HttpCookie). The issue I am having is that some systems that use this Cookie do not work successfully when a user has logged in with lowercase letters for in username. Is there a way to change the output of that Cookie to all UPPERCASE?

Answer (score 0):

Add .ToUpper() at the end of the "CookieName".Value

Example:
"CookieName".Value = Cookie.Identity.Name.ToUpper();